# Returning the address of a hlookup cell in excel

Tags: excel, offset

I did a HLOOKUP returned a value, however, I want to return another value right next to the HLOOKUPed figure. I tried using offset, but i need to know the address of the HLOOKUPed value first.
How can go about that

Comment: show your `HLOOKUP`, please, and some example data

Answer (score 2):

If with "right next" you mean a cell in the same row, then instead of Hlookup, use an Index/Match combination. For example

```
=HLOOKUP(A1,$E$1:$I$3,2,FALSE)
```

can be rewritten as

```
=INDEX($E$2:$I$2,MATCH(A1,$E$1:$I$1,0))
```

If you want to get the cell on the right of the matched cell use

```
=INDEX($E$2:$I$2,MATCH(A1,$E$1:$I$1,0)+1)
```

IF you want the cell to the left of the matched cell use

```
=INDEX($E$2:$I$2,MATCH(A1,$E$1:$I$1,0)-1)
```